# MongoDB conditionial update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running a bit in circles here and would appreciate some help. What I am looking to do is either update or create a nested object contained in an array depending on whether this object exists.

I have a users collection and a user document has the following structure:

```
{
  schema_version: 1,
  display_name: 'xxxxxx',
  email: 'xxxxxx',
  email_verified:'xxxxxx',
 ...
  custom_data: {

    stripe_id: 'xxx',
    subscriptions: [{
   subscription_id: xxxx,
    ....

     }],
 ...

  },
}
```

In webhook calls from Stripe I am getting a subscription object with a `subscription_id` and a `stripe_id`.
What I want to do is check if `subscription_id` exists, if so, update the document, if not then create the document in the subscriptions array **for the user document where `stripe_id` matches**.

If I do something along the lines of:

```
db.collection.update(
 {subscription_id: subscription.id},
 { $set: { 'custom_data.subscriptions': subscriptionData } },
 { upsert: true }
)
```

The problem is that I am creating subscription objects not bound to my user document where stripeID matches.

On the other hand, if I do something like this:

```
db.collection.update(
 {'custom_data.stripe_id': stripe_id},
 { $set: { 'custom_data.subscriptions': subscriptionData } },
 { upsert: true }
)
```

I will potentially end up creating dupes in the subscriptions array when, in fact I would want to update the existing object where subscription_id matches.

Is there any way to do that in one query with Mongo, or will I have to resort to using 2 queries in an if statement?

Thanks in advance for any clarification on this.

Comment: You can update the array element in case it exists, else insert a new element - you can do that in a single update operation. See the topic on Updates With Aggregation Pipeline. Also search for similar posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the followings with an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` with `$or` condition to search for `custom_data.subscriptions.subscription_id` or `custom_data.stripe_id`
2. `$addFields` with `$map` to conditional update your subscription object when matched
3. `$addFields` with `$setUnion` to insert an entry of incoming subscription object for the insert case
4. `$merge` to update the back into the original collection

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$custom_data.subscriptions.subscription_id",
              "xxxx"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$custom_data.stripe_id",
              "xxx"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "custom_data": {
        subscriptions: {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$custom_data.subscriptions",
            "as": "s",
            "in": {
              "$cond": {
                // if subscription_id matched, replace with your incoming object
                "if": {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$s.subscription_id",
                    "xxxx"
                  ]
                },
                "then": {
                  subscription_id: "incoming_sub_id"
                },
                // if not matched, keep the original object
                "else": "$$s"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "custom_data": {
        subscriptions: {
          // insert case; if the subscription array is empty, then union with your incoming object
          $setUnion: [
            "$custom_data.subscriptions",
            [
              {
                subscription_id: "incoming_sub_id"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vz87w7Y8xBL) for your reference.